# How to detect eye pupils and measure distance between pupils in iPhone

Tags: ios, core-image, face-detection

I have studied a lot of example about face detection and also I have detected the eye in iPhone using `CIDetector` and `HaarCascade_eye.xml`. But I want to detect the pupils of eye and want to measure the distance between pupils. Please guide me something so that I could do that.

Comment: i detected pupils through HUE color-space some time ago. The white area of an eye has very low saturation.But i used a Desktop system and had good light.

Comment: ..did you have any progress with this? If yes, i would appreciate it if you shared, thanks

Comment: No, i did not find any particular solution for that. So i cancelled the project.

Answer (score 4):

To calculate distance between two points using the following formula: [image: distance formula]

This will get center points of the two eyes (as detected by CIDetector) and compare their locations to output the measurements you're looking for.

```
if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition && faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)
{
    CGPoint leftEyeCenter = faceFeature.leftEyePosition;
    CGPoint rightEyeCenter = faceFeature.rightEyePosition;

    float simpleDistance = rightEyeCenter.x - leftEyeCenter.x;
    //This finds the distance simply by comparing the x coordinates of the two pupils

    float complexDistance = fabsf(sqrtf(powf(leftEyeCenter.y - rightEyeCenter.y, 2) + powf(rightEyeCenter.x - leftEyeCenter.x, 2)));
    //This will return the diagonal distance between the two pupils allowing for greater distance if the pupils are not perfectly level.       
}
```

Comment: It sounds like he wants to find the pupils also

Comment: @ColeJohnson His post seems to imply that he already has, he says that he used CIDetector to detect eyes, which in this case is the pupils. CIDetector returns CGPoints from the center of the detected point.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Thank you for the response. I have detected eyes but the center of eye is not exactly matching with the center of pupil so i want to detect pupils of eyes. It could be something like by detecting edge of pupils or something like that. So that i can properly detect the pupils and distance between pupils center.

Comment: @Dhariwal_Kuldeep did you get the answer ? I'm also stuck in the same situation.